# Suspicious proxy showing up in Google search results

Tags: discussion, google

This is Google's problem rather than Stackoverflow's, I guess. Yet, I thought it worthy of discussion since it got me fooled. Why is it that it came up so high in the search results, and is this guy Yusuf up to some shenanigans?

http://www.yusuf1201.tk/dex.pl/30/http/stackoverflow.com/questions/29030472/dbset-doesnt-have-a-find-method-in-ef7=3frq=3d1

[image: Sneaky Yusuf]

Comment: [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)